# Composite Factor Soup

Tags: code-golf, primes

Per the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, for a given number \$n\$, it is possible to find it's prime factors, and they are unique. Let's imagine we talk only of \$n\$ that is non-prime (composite).

We can also find the factors of all the composite numbers smaller than \$n\$. For example if \$n\$ is 10, then it has factors 5 and 2. 9 has 3 and 3. 8 has 2, thrice. 6 has 3 and 2. 4 has 2 and 2. So for the number 10, all the prime factors of all the composite numbers smaller than 10 would be listed as 2,3, and 5.

Now if you put a lot of vegetables in a pot for soup, often the largest will rise to the top. So if we put all of these factors in a big pot, which one will be the largest and rise to the top? For 10 soup, that answer is 5.

"Silly", you might think, "the number \$n\$ itself will have the largest factors, larger than the factors of numbers smaller than \$n\$". But this is where you are wrong my friend!

For example, the factors of 16 are all 2, repeated four times. The factors of 15 are 5 and 3, now, I don't have to be a mathematician to tell that 15 is smaller than 16, but 5 is bigger than 2!

Your challenge is to explore how this works for bigger \$n\$. For any number given input number \$n\$, assumed natural, composite, and less than 2^32, find out which is the "largest factor" of all the prime factors of all the composite numbers less than or equal to \$n\$.

Good luck and have fun!

Smallest byte count wins.

Comment: Isn't this just the largest prime below n/2?

Comment: xnor, Could it be the largest prime below or up to and including n/2? That would fit the '10' example in the question.

Comment: xnor probably... but can it be proven?

Comment: The proof is easy. The smallest composite number given some prime $p$ is $2p$. Therefore, a larger prime than $n/2$ cannot give a composite number less or equal to $n$ (upper bound). Conversely, the largest prime less or equal to $n/2$ will give have at least one composite number less or equal to $n$, namely, $2p$ (existence)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Neim](https://github.com/okx-code/Neim), 3 bytes

```
ᚺ>:
```

Explanation:

```
ᚺ   halve
 >  increment
  : previous prime
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0vNzP3//@GsXXZW//9bWloCAA)

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
;ÅPθ
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f@nBrwOEF//8bGhgYAAA) or [verify first \$[4,n]\$ numbers](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/ieXRHWaW9ksKjtkkKSvaV/60PtwYcXvBf57@hgQEA).

**Explanation:**

Implementation of the observation [@xnor's made in his comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/185381/composite-factor-soup#comment444372_185381): largest prime \$\leq\frac{1}{2}n\$. Which I've literally implemented now (after *@Arnauld* reported some bugs in my initial program):

```python
;     # Halve the (implicit) input
 ÅP   # Get a list of primes smaller than or equal to this
   à  # And only leave the largest prime
      # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Comment: This doesn't work: it returns 2 instead of 3 for input 7, and fails similarly for any number that's 2 * a prime + 1. Removing the `<` fixes it.

Comment: @Grimy `;>ÅM` was my original answer, which failed for `21` (resulting in `11` instead of `7`). But it should be fixed now by using `ÅP` (which is \$\leq\$) instead of `ÅM` (which is \$\lt\$).

Comment: Yes it is. :) (According to the spec, you should only consider composite inputs in \$[4,n]\$ but it doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 19 bytes

```
Prime@PrimePi[#/2]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n2b7P6AoMzfVAUwGZEYr6xvFqoHE8kqilXXt0hyUY9X0HYIS81Lyc4MTcwtyUqODU3NSk0uigWLpqdEmOsYGBgaxOopgAwIdlNVidQwNYv8DAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v1.4.5 [`-h`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), 6 bytes

```
z o fj
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.5&flags=LWg&code=eiBvIGZq&input=MTY)

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
‘HÆp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9RwwyPw20F////NzIEAA)

As others have observed, the answer is the largest prime \$≤ n/2\$

Thanks to @Arnauld for correcting my order of halving/incrementing

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 10 bytes

```
_4 p:-:@>:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/400UCqx0rRzsrP5rcilwpSZn5CukKRgawFiWlpYwppG5qRGMbW4JZxoZ/gcA)

Uses the xnor's observation

### Explanation:

```
_4 p:       the next prime smaller than 
        >:  the input  plus 1
     -:@    divided by 2
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 40 bytes

After a careful analysis of (xnor's comment on) the challenge, it turns out that  <s>42 41</s>  40 is the answer.

```javascript
n=>(g=k=>n%--k?g(k):k<2?n:g(--n))(n>>=1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FdBLTsMwFIXhOavwBNUWcVW/TcHpiFUgBlFoAqSyUYvYfvpncCTrfr5Hln@G/@E2Xr9//3Rtn@d1KmstvZzLUvr6qPVymuWijsurPdXjLLWuSsna98Wo9eXddyJ2InfiuRPmQCxhaAJBDGSZW0Mwi1nMYjYR3OEOc47gDne424xej3vcYx7zmMc8FrBAd8ADHvCAB7oDdyIesUh33B6LRzxuxn7CE56whCUssZvwjGW6M57xHD4e9lO7vg3jl6yi9GJs9dYu5/2lzQyexG4b7jhMkl9S6x0)

#### Commented

We look for the highest prime \$p\le\left\lfloor\dfrac{n}{2}\right\rfloor\$.

```javascript
n => (          // n = input
  g = k =>      // g = recursive function looking for the highest divisor k < n of n
    n % --k ?   //   decrement k; if k is not a divisor of n:
      g(k)      //     do recursive calls until it is
    :           //   else:
      k < 2 ?   //     if k is less than 2 (i.e. n is prime):
        n       //       stop recursion and return n
      :         //     else:
        g(--n)  //       try again with n - 1
  )(n >>= 1)    // initial call to g with n = floor(n / 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>34</s> 32 bytes

```
.+
$*
(.+)(?<!^\2+(..+))\1.*
$.1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLQ09bU8PeRjEuxkhbQw/I0Ywx1NPiUtEz/P/f0AwA) Edit: Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Grimy. Explanation:

```
.+
$*
```

Convert to unary.

```
(.+)
```

Find the largest number...

```
(?<!^\2+(..+))
```

... that is prime ...

```
\1.*
```

... and a factor of a number not greater than the input.

```
$.1
```

Convert to decimal.

Comment: [-2 bytes](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLQ09bU8PeRjEuxkhbQw/I0Ywx1NPiUtEz/P/f0AAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 37 bytes

```
: p ( n -- n ) 2 / primes-upto last ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqWQm1iSoVCcWliampecWgzm6hUUZeYC2QVFqSUllUBOXomCNZenn5VCQICz@38rhQIFDYU8BV1dIKGpYKSgrwDRoFtaUJKvkJNYDFT@v1rB0EDByFDBTMFEoVYhGqgnFmh4gYIe138A)

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 24+8 = 32 bytes

8 bytes for the `-rprime` flag (plus space) to import the Prime module. `Prime.each(n)` gets all primes up to `n`, then we just take the largest one. (We could take the last item since it's in order, but that costs more bytes.)

```ruby
->n{Prime.each(n/2).max}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZhvzX9curzqgKDM3VS81MTlDI0/fSFMvN7Gi9n@BQlq0SrxeSX58Zux/QwMuQzMuc3Pzf/kFJZn5ecX/dYsKQLr@6@YBAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
→`↑İp≤½
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ARoA5f9odXNr///ihpJg4oaRxLBw4omkwr3///8xMA)